# Python Equation

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion

For the question : McDonald’s sells Chicken McNuggets in packages of 6, 9 or 20 McNuggets. Thus, it is possible, for example, to buy exactly 15 McNuggets (with one package of 6 and a second package of 9), but it is not possible to buy exactly 16 McNuggets, since no non- negative integer combination of 6's, 9's and 20's add up to 16. To determine if it is possible to buy exactly n McNuggets, one has to find non-negative integer (can be 0) values of a, b, and c such that 6a+9b+20c=n .

The solution is

```
def McNuggets(n):

    if n == 0:
       return True
    if n < 0:
       return False

    return McNuggets(n-6) or McNuggets(n-9) or McNuggets(n-20)
```

How does Python choose between McNuggets(n-6), McNuggets(n-9) and McNuggets(n-20) ?

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't "choose between" them. It evaluates all of them. You're using the logical `or` operator on them, meaning that if any of them return `True`, it will evaluate to `True`.

Comment: Worth noting that it doesn't necessarily evaluate all of them since `or` is short-circuiting.

Comment: @Shashank That's a good point, but OP seems to be just learning Python, and I think that would just make my answer unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Woot! This post got me above 1k rep!

Comment: It could be helpful mentioning what the `or` statement would be useful for tho.

Answer (score 2):

One approach here is to generate a `set` of integers of the form 6a + 9b + 20c where a, b, c range from 0 to n where n = your target divided by 6, 9, or 20.

So for example, if n = 31, then generate a `set` of integers for 6 * a + 9 * b + 20 * c, for a in range (31/6), b in range(31/9) and c in range (31/20).

You could generate a list, instead of a set, if you find it easier.

Then return `n in possibilities`, where possibilities is the set. If you need to return the actual combinations, then you need to keep track of the number and the factors.

For example, 54 can be satisfied by 6 9's or 9 6's. 38 can be satisfied by a 20 and either 2 9s or 3 6's... :)

Have fun and post your solution.

For fun - how many ways can you buy 180 nuggets?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question about how that last line works.

Comment: These easiest way to figure out how the last line works is to print n at the start of the function. Do an easy case first, where n = 5, then try it for 6, then 7. That will be enough to figure out how it works. What it won't report is what the answer is, nor will it report multiple answers, because it will exit on the first successful combination.